# ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES on many ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a Chrome extension that makes around 250000 ajax call how can i handle them async not sync as sync will take forever but when i use async it gives me this error ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES what to do ?
note am using promises $.when

Comment: You're going to destroy your server. Why do you need to make 250,000 ajax calls?!?!

Comment: make loops to run and  collect a huge data

Comment: This smells like a bit of an issue in your app design.

Comment: @robertklep the code is huge willing to see it ?

Comment: @modz uhm not particularly, I'm afraid. Perhaps you could elaborate in your answer what exactly it is those AJAX calls are requesting.

Comment: @robertklep iam requesting a web page

Comment: @modz 250.000 times, though?